# How to set up a list that will present the percentage of target variable per group

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to have a list or a table that will present the percentage of "1"   and "0" in the "target" variable like in this example:
Data example:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " target  birds    wolfs     snakes
0        3        8         7
1        3        8         7
1        1        2         3
0        1        2         3
0        1        2         3
1        6        1         1
0        6        1         1
1        6        1         1",header = TRUE)
```

the desired output list:

```
birds    wolfs     snakes target=1 target=0 percentage
3         8          7      1        1         0.50
1         2          3      1        2         0.33
6         1          1      2        1         0.66
```

Any Ideas how set up such a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will work for you...

```
library(data.table)
dat_table = data.table(dat)
dat_table[,list(`target=1`=sum(target),
                `target=2`=length(target)-sum(target),
                percentage=sum(target)/length(target)),
          by=list(birds,wolfs,snakes)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I m new to R programming too. Here is alternative answer without using `data.table` 
i agree @vrajs5's answer is perfect

```
dat1 <- dat
dat1$target1 <- ifelse(dat1$target==1, 1,0)
dat1$target0 <- ifelse(dat1$target==0, 1,0)
dat2 <- dat1[,c(2:6)]
output <- aggregate(cbind(target1,target0) ~ birds + wolfs + snakes, data=dat2, FUN="sum")
output$percentage <- with(output, target1/(target1+target0))


> output
  birds wolfs snakes target1 target0 percentage
1     6     1      1       2       1  0.6666667
2     1     2      3       1       2  0.3333333
3     3     8      7       1       1  0.5000000
```

Comment: Thanks BeginneR, that's a nice solution too.

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want using the `table`function :

```
table(dat$birds,dat$target)

  0 1
1 2 1
3 1 1
6 1 2
```

Then, you'll have to manipulate data a bit with `cbind` and `rownames`, and you should get your desired output with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

...and a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
dat %.% group_by(birds, wolfs, snakes) %.%
    summarize(`target=1` = sum(target),
              `target=0` = n() - sum(target),
              percentage = round(`target=1` / n(), 2))
```